# Basic integration techniques question $\int\frac{e^{3x}}{e^x+1}dx$ (work is shown)

Tags: calculus

[Integration problem with work shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ADrM.jpg)

I am trying to figure out how I have created the $-\frac{3}{2}$ in the problem solution. I have been searching worlfram and symbolab and cant seem to find the step I messed up on. Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you for the help.

Comment: $C-\frac{3}{2}$ is the same thing as $C$

Comment: the substitution $e^x = t$ gives you a rational function which you probably can solve.

Comment: $C-3/2 = C_2$, for another constant $C_2$

Comment: $-\frac 32+C = K$

Comment: Dangg.. I feel so dumb. I starred at that for an hour... Thank you ya'll

Comment: @AlecFitzmaurice Please upvote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=C-\frac{3}{2}$. Then, you have found the same solution as the one in the book, since both K and C are just arbitrary constants. What you have shown is that the derivative of any function of the form
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}-e^x-\frac{3}{2}-\ln(e^x-1) + \text{some arbitrary constant}
$$
is
$$
\frac{e^{3x}}{e^x+1} \, .
$$
It doesn't matter how you label that constant. Sometimes different notations can 'conflict'—your '$C$' is different to the '$C$' in the book because you have added $-3/2$. However, this fact is immaterial. Try not to let notation get in the way of the actual mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

If you get
$$
\Big(\text{some function of } x \Big) - \frac 3 2 + \text{constant}
$$
and someone else gets
$$
\Big(\text{some function of } x \Big) + \text{constant}
$$
then you both got the same thing, but the other person is expressing it more efficiently.

For example, if your "constant" is $14.5$ and that other person's "constant" is $13$ than you both have the same function. In either case, if the "constant" is any number at all, then you have an antiderivative of the function you started with, and in either case, there exist no other antiderivatives than those that can be expressed by the expression given as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To compute $$I=\int \frac{e^{2x}}{e^x+1}e^xdx$$

put $ t=e^x$

then

$$I=\int \frac{t^2-1+1}{t+1}dt$$
$$=\int (t-1+\frac{1}{t+1})dt $$

$$=\frac{t^2}{2}-t+\ln(|t+1|)+K$$

replace $ t $ by $ e^x$.

You have taken $ K =C-\frac 32$.

Comment: Can the downvoter justify it.

Comment: It was unfair for someone to have downvoted your post, and so I have upvoted it. Your answer provides some variety to the others, since it explains how you would actually evaluate the integral.

Comment: @Joe Hey Joe, Thank you very much.